# Mysql Compare for the change in the price for today and yesterday data

Tags: python, mysql

I have MySQL table like below with sample data

```
timestamp  |aggregator_id|bare_media_cost
1589868086 | 2   | 0.2
1589868086 | 2   | 0.3
1589868086 | 1   | 2.012
1589868086 | 3   | 2.3535
1589868086 | 1   | 4.343
1589868086 | 2   | 5.43434
1589868086 | 3   | 6.0101
1589954506 | 1   | 7.222
```

I'm running the below query today morning to get data

```
 SELECT g1.aggregator_id as agid
      , round(SUM(g1.bare_media_cost/1000),2) AS "cost_one($)"
      , round(SUM(g2.bare_media_cost/1000),2) AS "cost_two($)"
   FROM TableHourly as g1 
   JOIN TableHourly as g2 
     ON g2.aggregator_id = g1.aggregator_id 
  WHERE g1.timestamp > 1589868086 
    and g2.timestamp < 1589954506 
  group 
     by agid;
```

I'm not sure this is correct, I know this has to do with an inner join but it is taking a long time to get data and can somebody highlight if I'm missing anything or correct if I'm doing wrong.

I want to get data by aggregator id to see a change in the cost for today and yesterday data

Here is the sample insert queries

```
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 1, 1.01);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.35);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 1, 0);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.35);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 522, 0.798246);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.1558761169);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 544, 0.44005601);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.175);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 544, 0.02596);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 1.7378481169);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 1, 0.179);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.175);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 1, 0.024);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.115183);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 1, 0.1);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.1125);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 1, 0.111);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.218440364);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 1, 0.416);
insert into TableHourly (timestamp,aggregator_id,bare_media_cost) values (1589880600, 481, 0.1125);

 CREATE TABLE TableHourly (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
timestamp VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
aggregator_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
bare_media_cost VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Replace src data table with CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO scripts. Show table-type desired result.

Comment: @Akina I didn't get, u want to include scripts as well here??

Comment: Scripts allows to look at the structure, to reconstruct source table, to test the answer code. Your table allows nothing above.

Comment: @Akina, yea, let me share

Comment: @Akina added, as there is a limit here, so added 20 queries only

Comment: 1) All data provided has the same `timestamp` value - so "yesterday" is not defined. 2) I convert your code into [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d738795f10f74d1e9e723e82a8b1dea). Edit source data, execute (ensure there is no errors), post new link into the question instead of code. 3) Add desired result for provided data (into the question, as formatted table). 4) Specify your MySQL version.